# org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to submit a flink job of version 1.11.3 . The actual application is developed in flink 1.8.1.
Since the Hadoop cluster is 3.2.0 apache I downloaded flink 1.11.3 (flink-1.11.3-bin-scala_2.11.tgz) and tried  to submit the job.
while submitting facing the below mentioned  exception . I have set the HADOOP parameters :

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH='hadoop classpath'
```

Is there any changes I need to do it the pom file to overcome this

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.

```
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:302)

at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)

at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:149)

at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:699)

at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:232)

at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:916)

at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:992)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)

at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)

at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:992)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.

```
at org.apache.flink.core.execution.DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.getExecutorFactory(DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.java:84)

at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1809)

at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:128)

at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:76)

at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1700)

at org.sapphire.appspayload.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.java:214)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:288)
```